# wordpress posting iframe as text

Tags: wordpress, iframe, embed

Fairly new to wordpress and I am having trouble with something that I would have thought was fairly simple. I am trying to post a video that comes from youtube and when I paste the code produced by the embed options, a like so:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/E783adREQ9c?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

In my post I get the actual text so:

Answer (score 0):

Anything you add to the editor will appear as text.

To add HTML, change the editor view from "Visual" to "Text" using the tabs in the top right corner.

However, for YouTube videos, you can actually paste the original URL (i.e. not the embed url) e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E783adREQ9c directly into the editor and WP will recognise it as a video and automatically embed it.